# Extracting results from a txt to csv

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to extract some results i've got into a csv file, from a text one.
The results.txt has this [form](https://github.com/JochenHiller/jvm-perftests/blob/master/SPECjvm2008/results/raspi2-linux-jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt-32bit-client/SPECjvm2008.002/SPECjvm2008.002.txt) and I wanted to extract it in the following form as csv:

```
Benchmark,        Pass/Fail,     ops/m
compiler.compiler, PASSED,       18.37
compress,          PASSED,       10.87
crypto.aes,        PASSED,        3.91
```

etc...

So I want to keep only the iteration 1 results, in that form. What would you suggest me to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged python as well as C++?

Comment: Also, some existing code that you wrote would be nice.

Comment: I suggest you start by *trying your self!* If you get problems with your attempt then you're welcome back here to ask about that problem. But before that read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am sorry about python, I can write it in c, or c++

Comment: i havent done it before, so that's why i asked for some suggestions, to start

Comment: Well this is tagged [tag:c], but it looks like a **classical** use-case for [tag:perl] ... still it's possible in C, of course.

Comment: I suggest typing `[c] csv` into the search box at the top, there are many questions asked before about csv.

Comment: Your example file shows no examples of fails?

Comment: it can be many forms of errors. The most secure is that, when it's not in exactly that form, i'll take is as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Python 2.x script should help to get you started (as was originally tagged). The `results.txt` file can be passed for lines containing `iteration 1` as follows:

```
import csv
from itertools import ifilter

with open('results.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(ifilter(lambda x: "iteration 1" in x, f_input), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Benchmark", "Pass/Fail", "ops/m"])

    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow([row[0], 'PASSED', row[6]])
```

Creating an output CSV file as follows:

```
Benchmark,Pass/Fail,ops/m
compiler.compiler,PASSED,18.37
compress,PASSED,10.87
crypto.aes,PASSED,3.91
crypto.rsa,PASSED,8.79
crypto.signverify,PASSED,15.10
derby,PASSED,9.40
mpegaudio,PASSED,7.81
scimark.fft.large,PASSED,4.27
scimark.lu.large,PASSED,0.85
scimark.sor.large,PASSED,2.38
scimark.sparse.large,PASSED,1.46
scimark.monte_carlo,PASSED,5.65
scimark.fft.small,PASSED,8.94
scimark.lu.small,PASSED,8.24
scimark.sor.small,PASSED,12.90
scimark.sparse.small,PASSED,5.61
serial,PASSED,4.53
startup.helloworld,PASSED,41.24
startup.compiler.compiler,PASSED,2.05
startup.compress,PASSED,3.62
startup.crypto.aes,PASSED,0.92
startup.crypto.rsa,PASSED,1.87
startup.crypto.signverify,PASSED,2.76
startup.mpegaudio,PASSED,1.82
startup.scimark.fft,PASSED,4.49
startup.scimark.lu,PASSED,2.44
startup.scimark.monte_carlo,PASSED,1.27
startup.scimark.sor,PASSED,3.14
startup.scimark.sparse,PASSED,1.54
startup.serial,PASSED,1.73
startup.sunflow,PASSED,3.55
startup.xml.transform,PASSED,0.27
startup.xml.validation,PASSED,4.28
sunflow,PASSED,3.69
xml.transform,PASSED,10.41
xml.validation,PASSED,15.37
```

However, it simply assumes all entries in the file are considered `PASSED` as there is no example showing what a failed entry would look like in the sample file.

Comment: i am trying to find a proper fail to see what is says. Thanks, you helped a lot!! One question... why the op/m is on 6th position of row?

Comment: The CSV library is splitting columns based on spaces. For the lines with `iteration 1` there will be an extra space.